# Elasticsearch java api index data pattern

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I create an index in elasticsearch `myindexname-YYYY-MM-DD` using the JAVA api  (not using logstash)?

I'm using this code right now:

```
final CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest("myindexname");
client.indices().create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you looked on the rollover api in elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-rollover-index.html ?